# Deserialize just read the first item

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I have the following xml elemnt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<os:FeatureCollection xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:hwtn="http://namespaces.os.uk/mastermap/highwaysWaterTransportNetwork/1.0" xmlns:net="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/net/4.0" xmlns:base="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/base/3.3" xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:gss="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gss" xmlns:gts="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gts" xmlns:gsr="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gsr" xmlns:gn="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/gn/4.0" xmlns:tn-w="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/tn-w/4.0" xmlns:tn="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/tn/4.0" xmlns:gmlxbt="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.3/xbt" xmlns:os="http://namespaces.os.uk/product/1.0" xmlns:highway="http://namespaces.os.uk/mastermap/highwayNetwork/2.0" xmlns:base2="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/base2/2.0" xmlns:ad="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/ad/4.0" xmlns:au="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/au/4.0" xmlns:bu-base="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/bu-base/4.0" xmlns:sc="http://www.interactive-instruments.de/ShapeChange/AppInfo" xmlns:cp="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp/4.0" xmlns:am="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/am/4.0" xmlns:su-core="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/su-core/4.0" xmlns:gmlexr="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.3/exr" xmlns:tn-ro="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/tn-ro/4.0" xmlns:network="http://namespaces.os.uk/mastermap/generalNetwork/2.0" xmlns:ram="http://namespaces.os.uk/mastermap/routingAndAssetManagement/2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://namespaces.os.uk/mastermap/highwaysWaterTransportNetwork/1.0 https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/xml/schema/highwaysnetwork/1.0/HighwaysWaterTransportNetwork.xsd http://namespaces.os.uk/mastermap/highwayNetwork/2.0 https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/xml/schema/highwaysnetwork/2.0/LinearHighwayNetwork.xsd http://namespaces.os.uk/product/1.0 https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/xml/schema/product/1.0/OSProduct.xsd http://namespaces.os.uk/mastermap/generalNetwork/2.0 https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/xml/schema/network/2.0/generalNetwork.xsd http://namespaces.os.uk/mastermap/routingAndAssetManagement/2.0 https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/xml/schema/highwaysnetwork/2.0/RoutingAndAssetManagement.xsd" gml:id="OS_HIGHWAYS">
<os:metadata xlink:href="https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/xml/products/Highways.xml"/>
  <os:featureMember>
    <ram:TurnRestriction gml:id="osgb4000000031265199">
      <gml:identifier codeSpace="http://inspire.jrc.ec.europa.eu/ids">http://data.os.uk/id/4000000031265199</gml:identifier>
      <net:networkRef>
        <net:LinkReference>
          <net:element xlink:href="#osgb4000000030462832"/>
          <net:applicableDirection xlink:title="in opposite direction" xlink:href="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/codelist/LinkDirectionValue/inOppositeDirection"/>
        </net:LinkReference>
      </net:networkRef>
      <net:networkRef>
        <net:LinkReference>
          <net:element xlink:href="#osgb4000000030462831"/>
          <net:applicableDirection xlink:title="in opposite direction" xlink:href="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/codelist/LinkDirectionValue/inOppositeDirection"/>
        </net:LinkReference>
      </net:networkRef>
      <net:inspireId>
        <base:Identifier>
          <base:localId>4000000031265199</base:localId>
          <base:namespace>http://data.os.uk/</base:namespace>
        </base:Identifier>
      </net:inspireId>
      <net:beginLifespanVersion>2016-06-17T00:00:00.000</net:beginLifespanVersion>
      <tn:validFrom nilReason="unknown" xsi:nil="true"/>
      <ram:restriction codeSpace="http://www.os.uk/xml/codelists/highways/TurnRestrictionValue.xml">No Turn</ram:restriction>
      <ram:reasonForChange codeSpace="http://www.os.uk/xml/codelists/ChangeTypeValue.xml">New</ram:reasonForChange>
    </ram:TurnRestriction>
  </os:featureMember>
</os:FeatureCollection>
```

and C# class is

```
[XmlArray(Namespace = "http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/net/4.0")]
[XmlArrayItem("LinkReference", IsNullable = false)]
public networkRefLinkReference[] networkRef {get; set;}
```

which has been created by XSD /c.

But When I use XmlSerializer.Deserialize to transfer XML to object, it just loads one networkRef.

I have changed the first attribute to the following and it does not work too.

```
[XmlArray("networkRef", Namespace = "http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/net/4.0")]
```

================== Edited ====== Add new class structure based on  jdweng comment but still not getting result.

```
      [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.Serializable]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("code")]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://namespaces.os.uk/mastermap/routingAndAssetManagement/2.0")]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://namespaces.os.uk/mastermap/routingAndAssetManagement/2.0", IsNullable = false)]
public class TurnRestriction
{
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2", IsNullable = true)]
    public identifier identifier { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("networkRef", IsNullable = true)]
    public NetworkRef[] NetworkRefs { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/net/4.0")]
    public inspireId inspireId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("restriction", IsNullable = true)]
    public TurnRestrictionRestriction[] Restriction { get; set; }

    public string id { get; set; }
}


 [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
    [System.Serializable]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("code")]
    [XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/net/4.0")]
    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/net/4.0", IsNullable = false)]
    public class networkRef
    {
        [XmlElement("LinkReference")]
        public networkRefLinkReference LinkReference { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: When you use XmlArray it will read two levels of tags both networkRef and LinkReference.  If you change XmlArray to XmlElement it will read only tag (then you need two classes).  When you change to networkReg you must change the class from networkRefLinkReference[] to networkRef[].

Comment: The XML you've included isn't valid - where are the namespace declarations for those prefixes? What does the full class look like? And the class that relates to `ram:TurnRestriction`? A [mcve] is required here.

Comment: @jdweng XSD has created this structure it actually created networkRef but not referring to it anywhere. I have changed classes to networkRef[] and inside it refers to networkRefLinkReference[] but now networkRef[] returns null.

Comment: Update the C# class that you have posted.  It is wrong.

Comment: @jdweng I have updated the question

Comment: [XmlRoot(ElementName : "networkRef", NameSpace....)] is needed above the class networkRef

Comment: @jdweng many thanks for your comments, unfortunately, it's not working yet. The first class structure was created by XSD and as you can see it ignores NetworkRef extra class but it was returning first item, does that mean the XML has a problem or XSD/deserializer can not read it properly.

Comment: This is pretty hard to help without a [mcve]. At the very least we need to see the class that relates to `ram:TurnRestriction` and everything relating to `networkRef` referenced within it.

Comment: @CharlesMager I have updated the question with almost all TurnRestriction class

Comment: Looks like you're nearly there. Add `Namespace = "http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/net/4.0"` to your `[XmlElement("networkRef")]` attribute.

Comment: @CharlesMager Many thanks it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below works

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication49
{

    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FeatureCollection));
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            FeatureCollection collection =  (FeatureCollection)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "FeatureCollection", Namespace = "http://namespaces.os.uk/product/1.0", IsNullable = false)]
    public class FeatureCollection
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "metadata", Namespace = "http://namespaces.os.uk/product/1.0")]
        public Metadata metadata  { get; set;}
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "featureMember", Namespace = "http://namespaces.os.uk/product/1.0", IsNullable = false)]
        public FeatureMember featureMember { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "metadata", Namespace = "http://namespaces.os.uk/product/1.0", IsNullable = false)]
    public class Metadata
    {
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "featureMember", Namespace = "http://namespaces.os.uk/product/1.0", IsNullable = false)]
    public class FeatureMember
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TurnRestriction", Namespace = "http://namespaces.os.uk/mastermap/routingAndAssetManagement/2.0", IsNullable = false)]
        public TurnRestriction turnRestriction { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "TurnRestriction", Namespace = "http://namespaces.os.uk/mastermap/routingAndAssetManagement/2.0", IsNullable = false)]
    public class TurnRestriction
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "identifier", Namespace = "http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2", IsNullable = false)]
        public Identifier identifier { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "networkRef", Namespace = "http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/net/4.0")]
        public NetworkRef[] networkRef { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "identifier", Namespace = "http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2", IsNullable = false)]
    public class Identifier
    {
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "networkRef", Namespace = "http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/net/4.0", IsNullable = false)]
    public class NetworkRef
    {
        [XmlElement("LinkReference", Namespace = "http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/net/4.0")]
        public LinkReference linkReference { get; set; }
    }
   [XmlRoot(ElementName = "LinkReference", Namespace = "http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/net/4.0", IsNullable = false)]
    public class LinkReference
    {
        [XmlElement("element", Namespace = "http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/net/4.0")]
        public Element element { get; set; }
    }    
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "element", Namespace = "http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/net/4.0", IsNullable = false)]
    public class Element
    {
    }   

}
```